# I'm having trouble selecting into an ARRAY of STRUCTS in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have read all the examples on the site, but none of them works for me. I have added the Brickhouse UDFS:
`create temporary function collect_struct as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF'` and

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF'
```

I have use examples from [Hive SELECT statement to create an ARRAY of STRUCTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270878/hive-select-statement-to-create-an-array-of-structs) and
 [Hive select data into an array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385425/hive-select-data-into-an-array-of-structs)

My SQL:

```
create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

CREATE TABLE test ( <br>
house_id bigint,<br>
first_name string,<br>
last_name string<br>
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES<br>
(1,"Bob","jones"),<br>
(1,"Jenny","jones"),<br>
(2,"Sally","johnson"),<br>
(3,"John","smith"),<br>
(3,"Barb","smith");

select house_id<br>
      ,collect(named_struct("first_name", first_name, "last_name", last_name))<br>
from test<br>
group by house_id;
```

I always get the same error:

> FAILED: ClassCastException
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardStructObjectInspector
>   cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your full stack trace with the error

Comment: That's the only error I get:

Comment: Please go to your JobTracker and track down the jobid of your hive job. locate the logs in it and it should show you detailed logs which got collected on different nodes for different attempts. Post when you can find them!

Comment: Hive doesn't create a job - it fails immediately:
`hive> select house_id
    >       ,collect(named_struct("first_name", first_name, "last_name", last_name))
    > from test
    > group by house_id;
FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardStructObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector
hive>`

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Hive version version 1.1.0 and was able to create an array of structs without needing the Brickhouse jar file's UDFs.  Try this.

```
SELECT house_id ,
       collect_list(named_struct("first_name", first_name, "last_name", last_name))
FROM house
GROUP BY house_id;

1   [{"first_name":"Bob","last_name":"jones"},{"first_name":"Jenny","last_name":"jones"}]   
2   [{"first_name":"Sally","last_name":"johnson"}]  
3   [{"first_name":"John","last_name":"smith"},{"first_name":"Barb","last_name":"smith"}]
```

Comment: This totally works. As stated, there is no need to use `breakhouse` jar file